# A subset of a Grassmanian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, grassmannians

Let $G = G(4, 7)$ denote the Grassmanian of $4$-dimensional linear spaces in $\mathbb{P}^7$. Let $F$ be a fixed primitive, non-singular, and geometrically irreducible homogeneous polynomial in $8$ variables, so that $X: F = 0$ is a geometrically integral and smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^7$. Let $H$ denote the subset of $G(4,7)$ consisting of those $L$ such that $X \cap L$ is singular. Does it follow that $H$ is a closed subset of $G$, in Zariski topology?

Comment: Yes, this follows from the openness of the smooth locus /closeness of the singular locus, applied to the zero locus of $F$ inside the universal family over $G$.